# Joining two tables, multiple rows into a single row different columns

Tags: sql, winsql

I have two tables.

```
USER

USER_ID | USER_NAME
--------------------
659    |  John  
660    |  Andrew 
661    |  Bianca
--------------------
```

```
USER_ADDRESS

USER_ID |TYPE |    ADDRESS
------------------------------
659     | HOME |    New York
659     | WORK |    New Jersey
660     | HOME |    San Francisco
660     | WORK |    Fremont
------------------------------
```

I want to join multiple records from the 2nd table into a single row on the 1st table.

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | HOME_ADDRESS | WORK_ADDRESS 
--------------------------------------------------
659   |  John    |   New York      | New Jersey
660   |  Andrew  |   San Francisco | Fremont
```

How do I get the above output in a select query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*, uah.address as home_address, uaw.address as work_address
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_address uah
    ON u.user_id = uah.user_id
    AND uah.type = 'HOME'
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_address uaw
    ON u.user_id = uaw.user_id
    AND uaw.type = 'WORK'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN?  Is it just in case they don't have any information stored in the USER_ADDRESS table but still want them to be displayed?